# How to calculate number of unique values in a column along with a criteria of another column

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory

I have to calculate the number of unique values in column group and number of people who will receive bonus in that group.

Dataset:

```
Bonus  | Group
Yes    | Hockey
No     | Cricket
No     | Football
Yes    | Tennis
No      Hockey
```

I used the pd.value_counts() to calculate the unique values in the group but I am stuck in how to get the number of people who get bonus in each group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `groupby.sum` on the boolean Series of the rows with bonus:

```
df['Bonus'].eq('Yes').groupby(df['Group']).sum()
```

Output:

```
Group
Cricket     0
Football    0
Hockey      1
Tennis      1
Name: Bonus, dtype: int64
```

If you don't care about the zeros:

```
df.loc[df['Bonus'].eq('Yes'), 'Group'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Hockey    1
Tennis    1
Name: Group, dtype: int64
```